# problem with maven webapp-cache.xml

Tags: java, maven-2, gwt, maven-war-plugin

We have a web application configured with maven. 
I have done a re-factoring (moved a file from one package to another) outside of eclipse, since this is not setup on eclipse and it is small fix. But, however I did forget to update reference to this file in a file.
Then I did `mvn clean install` 
surprisingly it is built successfully. Later it got failed on CI machine.

When I searched for text occurrences of the file I have re-factored, I have found an occurrence of this file name in `target\war\webapp-cache.xml` file.
It contain both references (old path, new path) of this re-factored file in it.

What is this file?
And did anybody else faced this problem?

**UPDATE**: We do use GWT in this project and when I did `mvn clean install` it deleted the target folder and then started compiling java sources,
then it started with compiling java into java script, after doing 12 permutations my build got struck. So, I did Ctrl+C to stop it and then I issued `mvn install` (without clean).

This seems to be the problem.

But before GWT starts with its compilation, java compilation should be completed and since this error (referring to non-existent java file) should have failed java compilation.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Maven war plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/inplace-mojo.html#cacheFile)

> cacheFile: The file containing the
>   webapp structure cache.
>
> ```
> * Type: java.io.File
> * Since: 2.1-alpha-1
> * Required: Yes
> * Default: ${project.build.directory}/war/work/webapp-cache.xml
> ```

This file is used by the war plugin to create the WAR file. It contains the structure of your final artifact so it will maintain the file references to everything that's included.

Comment: But I did run the mvn clean install, which should clean target folder. But it still contain old Object's path and also the new path.